# How can I add a pair of numbers to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` with the dimensions of certain shapes. My code is:

```
ArrayList<Double> shapes = new ArrayList<Double>();

shapes.add(2.5,3.5); 
shapes.add(5.6,6.5);
shapes.add(8.4,6.9);
```

I am aware this is doesn't work but how would I add a pair such as `(2.5,3.5)` to an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your own class:

```
public class MyClass {
   double x;
   double y;
   public MyClass(double x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

Then make an `ArrayList` of that type:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Adding to it:

```
MyClass pair = new MyClass(2.5,3.5);
shapes.add(pair);
```

If you want to get the `x` or the `y` coordinate, you can simply have additional methods in your class, for example `public double getX() { return x; }` and then you can do:

```
shapes.get(0).getX();
```

<sup>* This is only an example, modify the code as you see it fits your needs</sup>

Comment: Depending on your usecase you could also think about using java.awt.Dimension which is pretty much licke the mentioned custom class.

Comment: @piet.t That would be a waste. I prefer to have my custom class that serve my needs. Furthermore, I might want to change it in the future, using your own class gives you more flexibility.

Comment: You are passing two `int`s to the ctor instead of two `double`s.

Comment: As I said, it depends... When the intent is to really use it as a Dimension to set up some swing- or awt-widgets, I'd prefer Dimension. In other cases I'd also prefer a custom class. And looking at the other comments - yes, you can't use doubles in Dimension, so here a custom clas is mandatory.

Comment: This answer seems to be what I'm looking for. In addition, how would i call them. Let's say I add the dimensions of 10 distinct shapes. How can I display that info. Specifically the x and y variable of each dimension. I want to use System.out to display with appropriate text for each shape. So i would be calling specific elements of the array list.

Comment: @user3162117 You can have *getters* and *setters*. You can have `getX()` that returns `x`, then you can do `shapes.get(0).getX()`.

Answer (score 4):

This might be you are looking for

```
List<double []> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add(new double [] {2.5,3.5});
```

Still , prefer to use Maroun's Suggestion. That Looks clean to me, because later you may want to add more properties to that Shape object.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model class such as :

```
public class Dimensions{
   private double l;
   private double b;
  public Dimensions(double l, double b){
    this.l=l;
    this.b=b;
  }
  public void setL(double l){
   this.l=l;
  }
  public void setB(double b){
   this.b=b;
  }
  public double getB(){
   return this.b;
  }
  public double getL(){
   return this.l;
  }
}
```

Now you can add in arraylist by the following way:

```
ArrayList<Dimensions> shapes=new ArrayList<Dimensions>();
shapes.add(new Dimensions(2.5,3.5));
shapes.add(new Dimensions(5.6,6.5));
```

And access it by the following way:

```
double l;
double b;
for(Dimensions dimensions:shapes){
 l=dimensions.getL();
 b=dimensions.getB();
 //some more dimensions specific code goes here
}
```